# Unable to delete directory after creating it

Tags: java, directory

I'm trying to sequentially create and then delete a directory. However, it appears that deleting the directory is not working.

Does anyone has idea of why? Is it due to the file system not being refreshed in Java?

```
public boolean createDirectory(File file) {
    // Delete Directory if alreday exists
    if (file.exists()) {
        deleteDirectory(file);
    }
    boolean status = file.mkdirs();
    if (status) {
        System.out.println(" Successfull of creating Directory " + file.getPath());
    }
    return status;
}

public boolean deleteDirectory(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            File delFile = new File(dir, children[i]);
            if (!delFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Cannot find directory to delete" + delFile.getPath());
                return false;
            }
            boolean success = deleteDirectory(delFile);
            System.out.println(delFile + ": success? " + success);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("failure during delete directory" + delFile.getPath());
                return false;
            }
        }
        // The directory is now empty so now it can be smoked
        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is running on Windows, then the problem is usually that Windows won't delete a directory if any process is "using" it -- i.e., has a file from that directory (or one of its children) open, or has that directory (or one of its children) as its current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to create your own recursive delete method, I would suggest using one that is already well established. If you can, use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [FileUtils.deleteDirectory(java.io.File)](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29).